# How do I store a 100000*100000 matrix in C++?

Tags: c++

I have two vectors `a[100000]` and `b[100000]`. I want to store `a[i]*b[j]` in a `100000 x 100000` matrix `M`.  How can I do it in C++?

Comment: If you have enough memory use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), otherwise you could use a [memory mapped file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Comment: No i mean suppose I'm making a matrix T order n*n where each element A(i,j)=A(i)*B(j)

Comment: There are also many libraries which can handle [sparse matrixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) in a space-efficient way.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg No i have to store it while runtime from the user

Comment: So? Memory mapped files are still a valid way to store large amounts of run-time data (I'm guessing that's what you meant). Nothing says that the file has to be kept once you're done with the data. And sparse matrices or (if you have enough memory) a vector of vectors, or even a single vector are all still other valid possibilities.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: `a*b` is usually interpreted as the inproduct, a single scalar result created by summing `a[i] * b[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `std::vector<std::vector<your_type>>` to store the result.

```
int rows = 100000, cols = 100000;

std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;
result.resize(rows);

for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        result[i].resize(cols);
}    

for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
        result[i][j] = a[i] * b[j];
    }
}
```

Or you can **use a linear algebra library**, for example Eigen (you'll may have less to code with this), which **will surely be more efficient**.

Comment: This is highly inefficient. It has terrible memory locality and 100,000 unnecessary dynamic allocations. Prefer a single, flat vector of size `rows*cols` and overlay a 2D indexing scheme at the interface layer.

Comment: At least the lack of `.reserve()` in each child vector you can (and should!) fix quite easily.

Comment: The "inefficiency" is in the order of 40 bytes per MB of data. (0.004%). In exchange, you  don't need 40 GB of contiguous allocation.

Comment: Or just create it in one go: `std::vector<std::vector<double>> result { rows, std::vector<double>(cols) };`.

Comment: @MSalters: It's not just inefficient in memory volume required. There is an unnecessary performance problem at "initialisation" as well as an unnecessary performance problem at usage time, both of which I've addressed already. To me, this doesn't fall into the category of "premature optimisation; ignore it", but into the category of "there is literally no reason to use this naive and inherently slow technique".

Comment: Performance problem at initialization? No, filling 40 GB will be bandwidth-limited either way. Performance at usage time? Even less impact, as literally 99.999% of accesses are still linear.

Answer (score 2):

> The **NON-contiguity** part of this answer should be re-researched. It
>   may be wrong.

If you want to work with big number of element such as `100000*100000`. I would not recommend to use `vector of vectors` due to the "NON-contiguity" property of the inner `vectors` elements to each other. Small `push_back` may results in a lot of mess.

I would use single `vector` with a wrapper. See this for more information [Clean ways to write multiple 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994321/clean-ways-to-write-multiple-for-loops/20995125#20995125) .

Comment: Why do you think non-contiguity is bad? It's probably useful here.

Comment: mmmm to be honest with you I did not have a deep thought of it.. it is something I used to hear always. Anyway, I can think of some reasons. Like, you can not apply something like std::max_elemnt for example in one batch .. you have to go for each row separately. mmm I am rethinking. it is not about contiguity because you can do this for std::list it is about iterators.. mmmm again, I do not know!

Comment: Contiguity helps if you can keep elements which are used together on the same page (within 4KB). But elements in adjacent rows are separated by 400 kB in the contiguous case. And if you want the maximum element of a 40 GB matrix, you'd better check `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` how many threads you should be creating for that. Then divide the 100.000 rows over your threads, and call `std::max_element` on each row.

Comment: Many thanks. I am going to read more about the method you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <vector>
    class C
    {
    public:
        C(const std::vector<double>& a_, const std::vector<double>& b_)
            :a(a_),b(b_){};
        double operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const { return a[i]*b[j]; }
    private:
         std::vector<double> a, b;
    };
```

**What the problem actually is?**

The original question asks about a way to save `C(i,j)=A(i)*B(j)` to a matrix.

From an OOP point of view, such an `matrix` can be defined as an object with a method takes two inputs(`i` and `j`), and returns a result (`ret=A(i)*B(j)`).

This could be implemented using nested array subscriptions(`c[i][j]`), or linear array indexing(`c[i*100000+j]`), or a function (`c.get(i, j)`). The third way could also be simplified to a functor (`c.operator()(i, j)` or `c(i, j)`).

**Then what?**

If you agree to all above that any of the three interfaces serves the purpose, or at least partially (like I mentioned in the comment, if the matrix is only required to provide random **read** access to its elements). Then we continue to implement one of them, 3rd one being my choice.

**Why do it that way?**

My observation is that, computing the return value is not expensive, so why not calculate the product "lazily" when the product is actually accessed?

In this way, the storage is very efficient (memory usage is reduced from `n^2` to `2n`).

Hiding the multiplication in the getter function does not significantly increase access time (two memory accesses and one multiplication, compared with the ideal case being one memory access only, but both cases are constant time, and this implementation is much more cache friendly for the reduced size of the data).

**So, instead of saving the product, just save the inputs, but calculate the product when a particular element is accessed.**

**What is missing?**

Although manipulating this "matrix" is possible ( by changing the member `a` and `b`), it does not allow changing arbitrary element to arbitrary value.

Member functions that implements array slicing (like `c(0:10:end, 4)`) is not present either, but is feasible.

**Test code**

```
int main() {
    C c({1,2,3,4},{10,20,30,40}); // a={1,2,3,4}; b={10,20,30,40}
    cout << "3*30 "<<c(2,2);      // c(2, 2) = a[2]*b[2] = 3*30 = 90
    return 0;
}
```

**Demo**

http://ideone.com/bZR7AU

Comment: Well, I think this answer deserves the donwvote because the class is not really a matrix (it lacks the random write-access, like you can not add/multiply another arbitrary matrix of a compatible size to it and store the result back). But if you only read from this matrix then I don't think this is a bad solution. IMHO the question is itself an x-y problem.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question, and there is a lack of explanation

Comment: @Pierre explanation added.

Comment: I am not sure about the answer. Most likely calculating `A[i,j] = B[i] * C[j]` was only a step in a much bigger task.

Answer (score 0):

Using an in-RAM `std::vector<double>` would probably not feasible if you have less than 80GB of RAM in your system (for a 100000×100000 matrix of doubles).

Here is how you would do this using an mmap'd file. Please see the inline comments:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 1000
#define COLS 1000
#define FILENAME "./matrix.doubles"

int main(void)
{
    double (*matrix)[ROWS][COLS]; // pointer to our matrix
    int fd; // file descriptor of backing file

    // open backing file
    fd = open(FILENAME,
              O_CREAT | O_RDWR, // create (if absent) and/or read and writable
              S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); // (only) user may read and write
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Could not open file");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((lseek(fd, sizeof(*matrix), SEEK_SET) == (off_t) -1) ||
        ftruncate(fd, sizeof(*matrix)) ||
        (lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET) == (off_t) -1)) {
        perror("Could not set file size.");
        return 1;
    }

    matrix = mmap(NULL, // I don't care were the address starts
                  sizeof(*matrix), // size of matrix in bytes
                  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, // readable and writable
                  MAP_PRIVATE, // we access the data exclusively
                  fd, // file descriptor of backing file
                  0); // offset
    if (matrix == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Could not mmap file.");
        return 1;
    }

    // operate on matrix
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
        for (unsigned col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) {
            (*matrix)[row][col] = row * col;
        }
    }

    // close backing file
    munmap(matrix, sizeof(*matrix));
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

This is pure C code. You could fancy up the code by using e.g. [`std::array<double, ROWS, COLS>&`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a bare array, but I think the idea should be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

If you can compute a[i]*b[j] on the fly then you should do that because of two reasons:

- Obtaining the results from a huge matrix may not be faster than compute the product of two double values on the fly.
- 10000x10000 double matrix requires 80 Gbytes of storage (in-memory or on disk) and some extra work might be needed to access pre-computed data.

In my example below, I see 30x speed up (compiled in release mode using clang 3.8) if I compute the product of two double values on the fly for N=20000.

```
template <typename T>
void test_lookup(std::vector<T> &data, std::vector<size_t> &index,
                 std::vector<T> &results) {
    const size_t LOOP = index.size() / 2;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < LOOP; ++idx) {
        auto row = index[2 * idx];
        auto col = index[2 * idx + 1];
        results[idx] = data[col * LOOP + row];
    }
}

template <typename T>
void test_mul(std::vector<T> &x, std::vector<T> &y, std::vector<T> &results) {
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < x.size(); ++idx) {
        results[idx] = x[idx] * y[idx];
    }
}
```