# gets function for 2 dimensional array(String)

Tags: c++, c, string, gets

The `gets()` function has only one parameter char* TYPE. I also know that the array's name is an address. EX) `char buff[10][20]` , address : buff

1) if there is a N dimensional array, the name of this array is also an address?

2) but when i'm asserting the argument of `char buff[10][20]` in to the gets() function. EX) `gets(buff)` there is a compile error calling that `buff[10][20]` cannot transfer to a `char*` but isn't buff also a address therefore an char*?

3) however when i assert *buff as a argument in gets function it works. EX) `char buff[10][20]; gets(*buff);` I'm able to approach to `buffer[0]`. If the *buff is an `char*` TYPE doesn't it mean that buff is a double pointer type? Am i getting it right?

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267097/pass-2d-array-in-function-2d-array-received-is-pointer-array).

Comment: `gets` has been removed from the C language, don't use that function.