# When passing 2d array to function what is the difference between single pointer and double pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

We can pass a 2d array as a single pointer and as well as a double pointer. But in the 2nd case the output is not as expected. So what is wrong in the 2nd code?

**Method 1:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(int *arr, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));
}

int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    print((int *)arr, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**Method 2:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(int *arr[], int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));
}

int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3;
    int n = 3;
    print((int **)arr, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 3 5 7 9 3 0 -1990071075 0
```

Comment: "We can pass a 2d array as a single pointer and as well as a double pointer" - you could pass it as a quadruple pointer to `char`. That doesn't mean its a good idea, or defined behavior to utilize (and it isn't, and its not). That hard-cast to `int**` and the failure of the code to compile without it should hint you something wicked this way comes. An `int**` is a pointer to pointer to `int` The *legal* conversion of `arr` to pointer as an expression is `int (*)[3]`. Those types are *not equivalent*. Arrays are not pointers, regardless of what you may have been led to believe.

Comment: A rule of thumb in C is to avoid 2D arrays. Just use a 1D array and access it as `a[i*width+j]` ...

Comment: But @BasileStarynkevitch in my project I have to pass 2D array to function so I can't avoid 2D array

Comment: You can *always* avoid 2D arrays: they don't exist in the hardware, and C is (or was) a language designed to be close to the hardware.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch can you give me a simple example?

Comment: I gave it already in my first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is undefined behavior: [Accesing a 2D array using a single pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303647/accesing-a-2d-array-using-a-single-pointer).

The second one is simply wrong, you can't pass a 2D array (`arr[][3]`) to an array of `int` pointers (`*arr[]`), take a look to [Correct way of passing 2 dimensional array into a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function):

```
void print(int *arr[], int m, int n)
```

Must be

```
void print(int arr[][3], int n) /* You don't need the last dimesion */
```

or

```
void print(int (*arr)[3], int n) /* A pointer to an array of integers */
```

> But this way the column in arr[][3] must be globally defined. Isn't
>   any other workaround?

Under C99 you can use VLA's (Variable-length array):

```
void print(int rows, int cols, int arr[rows][cols])
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but the way i see it, he treats a matrix as a linearized array (calculating indexes) without actual indexation, which i belive is perfectly legal (frist case).

Comment: But this way the column in arr[][3] must be globally defined. Isn't any other workaround?

Comment: @PankajMahato, under C99 you can use [VLA's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Comment: @HighPredator It's not legal according to the standard, but you can get away with it most of the times.

Comment: @MarekVavrusa, that's what I'm trying to figure out. How come it can be UB if for example i calculated a pointer address correctly, the element is there and I'm not outside of the memory block? Btw. can you link the standard paragraph, so I wouldn't be asking more of seemingly stupid questions?

Comment: @HighPredator It's already linked in the Alter Mann's answer (first paragraph).

Comment: The first one is correct; you misunderstood the article you linked to. `(int *)arr` means we are iterating over all of `arr`; the other question features `&a[0][0]` which means we are only iterating over `a[0]`

Comment: @PankajMahato yes, you can always "flatten" a true array (so long as you're careful to get the pointer from `arr` or `&arr`, rather than from a sub-array as in the article linked by Alter Mann)

Comment: @PankajMahato No it isn't read the first paragraph in the linked standard. You can get away with it, but you shouldn't use it like this.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, `If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: @AlterMann, now I'm totally lost... Regarding the case 1, it's UB because? Because the resulting pointer type is wrong or what?

Comment: @HighPredator, because you can't treat an  `int arr[3][3]` as an  `int arr[9]`, have you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7787436/1606345)?, Christoph explains it very well.

Comment: @AlterMann the example you liked is only UB because of `&foo[0][0]`; it would be OK if that was replaced with `(int *)foo`

Comment: @MattMcNabb, again, accessing one past the last element of the array is UB, OP uses a 1D array, thus accessing `arr[1][0]` is UB, if you do not agree with this tell it to the standard.

Comment: @AlterMann If we point to `arr` then "the array object" is `arr` (not `arr[0]`). Also, you say "OP is passing a 1D array" but arrays cannot be passed by value in C. OP is passing a pointer which is bounded to all of `arr` (not a suboject of arr). The wording in your bolded quote is imprecise because it does not clearly say *which* array object when there are nested arrays, however in accordance with the rationale of allowing bounds-checked pointers, a pointer should be bounded according to the object it was pointed to (not some subobject of that)

Comment: before anyone says "`but (int *)arr` is not pointing to an element of `arr`", think about `char *p = (char *)&arr[0][0]; p += 2;`. Does that cause UB? After all, neither `p` nor `p + 2` point to any elements of `arr` or its sub-arrays.

Comment: Matt, it is defined as such (UB), because type `int *arr[]` ambiguously represents an array of `int*`, in which case treating it as a contiguous block of memory would fail, or an array of arrays in which it usually works. Usually because the compiler *may* insert padding between the sub-arrays for aliasing. Your argument that all compilers must generate multi-dimensional arrays in contiguous memory on the basis that your compiler does it is false, the standard says they don't have to.

Comment: @MarekVavrusa, hold on a second. What you're saying goes against the answer from the link. Specifically: "C arrays - even multi-dimensional ones - are contiguous, ie an array of type int [4][5] is structurally equivalent to an array of type int [20]."

Comment: @MarekVavrusa, well ... as far as I know multidimesional arrays (`int arr[][3]`) must be in contiguous memory.

Comment: @MarekVavrusa, in other words, `sizeof(int arr[3][3])` = `sizeof(int arr[3] * 3)` there can't be padding bytes.

Comment: @All, I think i found the proper explanation I was looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25140160/3651664

Comment: @AlterMann, thx for pointing that fact out in the first place. Sorry if I bothered you too much, but that stuff really bugged me out:)

Comment: @AlterMann @HighPredator I think my wording was poor. The "standard doesn't say" is not equal to "standard says not". I admit, the array subscription in C / pointer aliasing is shady. Sure that `int [4][5]` and `int [4*5]` may have a same size, and therefore may be considered as equal, but they're not. My understanding of the standard in this is case is that out-of-bounds access (this cover "linearization" in the OP's question for anything other than `char`) is not defined not only because the C originally wanted to do bounds checking, but also to comply with aligned members.

Comment: @HighPredator note the distinction between `a[1][7]` which goes out of bounds of `a[1]`, and `((int *)a)[12]` which is OK because we were never anything to do with `a[1]` or any other sub-array of `a`.; it's still in the bounds of `a`

Answer (score 1):

Alter Mann is right, but the main problem in Method 2 is this code:

```
*((arr+i*n) + j)
```

Since `arr` is now type of `int *arr[]`, the element size is `sizeof(int *)` and not `sizeof(int)` as in the first case. So when f.e. `arr = 0`, then `arr + 1` equals to `0 + sizeof(int*)` instead of `0 + sizeof(int)` as in the first case. It would work okay if the `arr` was casted to `(int*)` like:

```
*(((int *)arr+i*n) + j)
```

*TL;DR you're jumping through the array by the pointer size, not an integer size.*

My personal suggestion is to use pointers, but access it like an array:

```
int *arr[];
return arr[i][j];
```

This works every time unlike the pointer arithmetic that might bite you with the step size, like it did with your case.

Comment: Just to make things a bit clearer: it's UB because the result of pointer type (from the OP's example) after pointer arithmetic differs from int*, thus, a cast is required?

Comment: It's not UB, it's just reading out-of-bounds. On X86_64, the program reads memory on positions `[0, 8, 16, 24, 32 ...]` instead of `[0, 4, 8, ...]` because the step size is different. To illustrate this, try printing: `(int*)NULL + 1` and `(int)0 + 1` and see how it differs.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `*((arr+i*n) + j)` in Method 1 (other than it is harder to read than `arr[i*n+j]`  . Are you talking about Method 2 or what?

Comment: There is, as with my response to Alter Mann's answer (standard). I'm showing why the Method 2 is wrong.

Comment: OK, I'd suggest editing your answer to say that you are talking about Method 2