# casting pointer to array into pointer

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Consider the following C code:

```
int arr[2] = {0, 0};
int *ptr = (int*)&arr;
ptr[0] = 5;
printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
```

Now, it is clear that the code prints `5` on common compilers. However, can somebody find the relevant sections in the C standard that specifies that the code does in fact work? Or is the code undefined behaviour?

What I'm essentially asking is why `&arr` when casted into `void *` is the same as `arr` when casted into `void *`? Because I believe the code is equivalent to:

```
int arr[2] = {0, 0};
int *ptr = (int*)(void*)&arr;
ptr[0] = 5;
printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
```

I invented the example while thinking about the question here: [Pointer-to-array overlapping end of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243116/pointer-to-array-overlapping-end-of-array/29243717) ...but this is clearly a distinct question.

Comment: Let me look this up for you. The general idea is that a pointer to a compound type (union / struct / array) can be casted into a pointer to its first member.

Comment: Great question. I've wondered the exact same thing in more than one occasion in the past. One would almost think that &arr should yield a ** pointer.

Comment: Well, &arr yields a data type `int(*)[2]` and you really need the cast, otherwise the compiler would warn.

Comment: @1sand0s: No, it wouldn't make sense for `&arr` to yield an `int**`, since there is no `int*` object for it to point to.

Comment: @juhist: In fact `int *ptr = &arr;` is a constraint violation. A conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic. That diagnostic can be either a warning or a fatal error. (IMHO it *should* be a fatal error by default, but the authors of gcc, for example don't seem to agree.)

Comment: @KeithThompson And yet, it is an address of an address :-) Otherwise, what is it? It's not like the compiler doesn't have a place to store the address of the address although opaque and implementational. Just thinking out loud. Could be off base.

Comment: I don't see a guarantee in the standard that `(int*)&arr == &arr[0]`. In particular, citing the [N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the semantics of pointer conversion in 6.3.2.3p7 don't cover this case.

Comment: @1sand0s: No, `&arr` absolutely is not the address of an address. It is the address of an array object. (The operand of unary `&` is one of the three contexts in which an array expressions is not implicitly converted to a pointer.)

Comment: @1sand0s, arrays have some weird behaviour like that. Using the array name in most contexts causes it to decay into a pointer to the first element of the array. One context where that *doesn't* happen is when the array name is the argument of the unary `&` operator.

Comment: @1sand0s: Because `arr` **is not an address**. Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays. `arr` is the name of an array object. When the name `arr` appears as an expression, it is (in most but not all contexts) implicitly converted to a pointer to the array object's first element. Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243116/pointer-to-array-overlapping-end-of-array/29243717 then? Am I correct that you not finding a guarantee in the standard that (int*)&arr == &arr[0] would mean that that question would be undefined behaviour? See my answer to that question which tries to explain why the code works.

Comment: @KeithThompson re-reading your answer (the parenthetical part), I now understand what you're saying and assume you are far better acquainted with the specification than I am. I couldn't edit my answer before you replied but figured out what you were saying ex post facto.

Comment: @juhist: My not finding a guarantee could very easily mean that I'm missing something. I would expect the code to work as expected for any real-world implementation. I just haven't been able to prove that the standard *requires* it to work.

Comment: I think I'm going to make an interpretation request pertaining this.

Answer (score 6):

For unions and structures, cf. ISO 9899:2011§6.7.2.1/16f:

> 16 The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>
> 17 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

For array types, the situation is a bit more complex. First, observe what an array is, from ISO 9899:2011§6.2.5/20:

> An *array type* describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the *element type*. The element type shall be complete whenever the array type is specified. Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number of elements in the array. An array type is said to be derived from its element type, and if its element type is *T*, the array type is sometimes
>   called “array of *T*”. The construction of an array type from an element type is called “array type derivation”.

The wording “contiguously allocated” implies that there is no padding between array members. This notion is affirmed by footnote 109:

> Two objects may be adjacent in memory because they are adjacent elements of a larger array or adjacent members of a structure with no padding between them, or because the implementation chose to place them so, even though they are unrelated. If prior invalid pointer operations (such as accesses outside array bounds) produced undefined behavior, subsequent comparisons also produce undefined behavior.

The use of the `sizeof` operator in §6.5.3.5, Example 2 expresses the intent that there is also no padding before or after arrays:

> **EXAMPLE 2**
>
> Another use of the sizeof operator is to compute the number of elements
>   in an array:
>
> ```
> sizeof array / sizeof array[0]
> ```

I therefore conclude that a pointer to an array, converted to a pointer to the element typo of that array, points to the first element in the array. Furthermore, observe what the definition of equality says about pointers (§6.5.9/6f.):

> 6 Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer
>   to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.<sup>109)</sup>
>
> 7 For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.

Since the first element of an array is “a subobject at its beginning,” a pointer to the first element of an array and a pointer to an array compare equal.

Comment: Well, I hope you find something; @Keith Thompson couldn't find anything. It seems that your reasoning is sane and I have now no doubt why common compilers treat pointer to an array as a pointer to its initial member (as in have the same address, not as in have the same type).

Comment: "element typo" -- *chuckle*

Comment: I agree with your reasoning about the representation of arrays. I don't agree that your conclusion follows rigorously from the representation.

Comment: @KeithThompson This was just an intermediate save because someone *cough cough* thought it would be a good idea to edit the answer concurrently.

Comment: Sorry about the concurrent edit. I *think* I can describe a deliberately perverse implementation that conforms to the standard but breaks your assumptions. Details later.

Comment: Yeah, I think that too. I'm currently in the process of filing a defect report, so stay tuned.

Comment: I was thinking I could describe a perverse but conforming implementation where a pointer is represented as the address of the *last* byte of the object it points to. Conversions to and from `char*` or `void*` would adjust the offset. But I couldn't reconcile pointers to incomplete types.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly refactored version of your code for easier reference:

```
int arr[2] = { 0, 0 };
int *p1 = &arr[0];
int *p2 = (int *)&arr;
```

with the question being: Is `p1 == p2` true, or unspecified, or UB?

---

Firstly: I think that it is intended by the authors of C's abstract memory model that `p1 == p2` is true; and if the Standard doesn't actually spell it out then it would be a defect in the Standard.

Moving on; the only relevant piece of text seems to be C11 6.3.2.3/7 (irrelevant text excised):

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. [...] When converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.
>
> When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

It doesn't specifically say what the result of the first conversion is. Ideally it should say *...and the pointer points to the same address*, but it doesn't.

However, I argue that it it is implied that the pointer must point to the same address after the conversion. Here is an illustrative example:

```
void *v1 = malloc( sizeof(int) );
int  *i1 = (int *)v1;
```

If we do not accept "*and the pointer points to the same address*" then `i1` might not actually point into the `malloc`'d space, which would be ridiculous.

My conclusion is that we should read 6.3.2.3/7 as saying that the pointer cast does not change the address being pointed to.  The part about using pointers to character type seems to back this up.

Therefore, since `p1` and `p2` have the same type and point to the same address, they compare equal.

Comment: Notice that as per §6.2, conversions between compatible types do not alter the value stored in the type.

Comment: @FUZxxl do you mean 6.3/2 "Conversion of an operand value to a compatible type causes no change to the value or the representation."?  The term *compatible type* is defined by 6.2.7 and it basically means that the types are the same. Two pointers to different types are not compatible.  (In fact, since pointers to different types may have different size and representation; in general, pointer casts may change the representation).

Answer (score 0):

To answer directly:

**Can somebody find the relevant sections in the C standard that specifies that the code does in fact work?**

- 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators, paragraph 1
- 6.3.2.3 Pointers, paragraphs 1,5 and 6
- 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators, paragraph 3

**Or is the code undefined behaviour?**

The code **you** posted is not undefined, but it "might" be compiler/implementation specific (per section 6.3.2.3 p5/6)

**What I'm essentially asking is why `&arr` when casted into `void *` is the same as `arr` when casted into `void *`?**

This would imply asking why `int *ptr = (int*)(void*)&arr` gives the same results as `int *ptr = (int*)(void*)arr;`, but per your code posted, you're actually asking why `int *ptr = (int*)(void*)&arr` gives the same as `int *ptr = (int*)&arr`.

Either way I'll expand on what your code is actually doing to help clarify:

Per 6.3.2.1p3:

**Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined**.

and per 6.5.3.2p3:

**The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’.**

So in your first declaration

`int arr[2] = {0, 0};`

`arr` is initialized to an array type containing 2 elements of type `int` both equal to 0. Then per `6.3.2.1p3` it is "decayed" into a pointer type pointing to the first element anywhere it is called in scope (**except when it's used like `sizeof(arr)`, `&arr`, `++arr` or `--arr`**).

So in your next line, you could simply just do the following:

`int *ptr = arr;` or `int *ptr = &*arr;` or `int *ptr = &arr[0];`

and `ptr` is now a pointer to an int type that points to the first element of the array `arr` (i.e. `&arr[0]`).

Instead you declare it as such:

`int *ptr = (int*)&arr;`

Lets break this down into it's parts:

1. `&arr` -> triggers the exception to `6.3.2.1p3` so instead of getting `&arr[0]`, you get the address to `arr` which is an `int(*)[2]` type (not an `int*` type), so you are not getting a `pointer to an int`, you are getting a `pointer to an int array`
2. `(int*)&arr`, (i.e. the cast to `int*`) -> per 6.5.3.2p3, `&arr` takes the address of the variable `arr` returning a pointer to the type of it, so simply saying `int* ptr = &arr` will give a warning of **"incompatible pointer types"** (since `ptr` is of type `int*` and `&arr` is of type `int(*)[2]`) which is why you need to cast to an `int*`.

Further per 6.3.2.3p1: **"a pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer"**.

So, you're declaration of `int* ptr = (int*)(void*)&arr;` would produce the same results as `int* ptr = (int*)&arr;` because of the types you are using and converting to/from. Also as a note: `ptr[0] = 5;` is the same as `*ptr = 5`, where `ptr[1] = 5;` would also be the same as `*++ptr = 5;`

Some of the references:

**6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**

> 1. An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially designates an object (*see note); if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a constqualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a constqualified type.
>
> *The name ‘‘lvalue’’ comes originally from the assignment expression E1 = E2, in which the left operand E1 is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an object ‘‘locator value’’. What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described as the ‘‘value of an expression’’. An obvious example of an lvalue is an identifier of an object. As a further example, if E is a unary expression that is a pointer to an object, *E is an lvalue that designates the object to which E points.
>
> 2. Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion. If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the unqualified version of the type of the lvalue; additionally, if the lvalue has atomic type, the value has the non-atomic version of the type of the lvalue; otherwise, the value has the type of the lvalue. If the lvalue has an incomplete type and does not have array type, the behavior is undefined. If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.
>
> 3. Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

**6.3.2.3 Pointers**

> 1. A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.
>
> 5. An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation (the mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment).
>
> 6. Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

**6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**

> 1. The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier.
>
> 3. The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’. If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue. Similarly, if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator. Otherwise, the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand.
>
> 4. The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined (*see note). 
>
> *Thus, &*E is equivalent to E (even if E is a null pointer), and &(E1[E2]) to ((E1)+(E2)). It is always true that if E is a function designator or an lvalue that is a valid operand of the  unary & operator, *&E is a function designator or an lvalue equal to E. If *P is an lvalue and T is the name of an object pointer type, *(T)P is an lvalue that has a type compatible with that to which T points. Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the  address of an object after the end of its lifetime.

**6.5.4 Cast operators**

> 5. Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the value of the expression to the named type. This construction is called a cast (a cast does not yield an lvalue; thus, a cast to a qualified type has the same effect as a cast to the unqualified version of the type). A cast that specifies no conversion has no effect on the type or value of an expression.
>
> 6. If the value of the expression is represented with greater range or precision than required by the type named by the cast (6.3.1.8), then the cast specifies a conversion even if the type of the expression is the same as the named type and removes any extra range and precision.

**6.5.16.1 Simple assignment**

> 2. In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

**6.7.6.2 Array declarators**

> 1. In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the [ and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero. The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type. The optional type qualifiers and the keyword static shall appear only in a declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost array type derivation.
>
> 3. If, in the declaration ‘‘T D1’’, D1 has one of the forms:
>
> D[ type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expressionopt ]
> D[ static type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expression ]
> D[ type-qualifier-list static assignment-expression ]
> D[ type-qualifier-listopt * ]
>
> and the type specified for ident in the declaration ‘‘T D’’ is ‘‘derived-declarator-type-list T’’, then the type specified for ident is ‘‘derived-declarator-type-list array of T’’.142) (See 6.7.6.3 for the meaning of the optional type qualifiers and the keyword static.)
>
> 4. If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is * instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size, which can only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope;143) such arrays are nonetheless complete types. If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type. (Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.)
>
> 5. If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by *; otherwise, each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero. The size of each instance of a variable length array type does not change during its lifetime. Where a size expression is part of the operand of a sizeof operator and changing the value of the size expression would not affect the result of the operator, it is unspecified whether or not the size expression is evaluated.
>
> 6. For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value. If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values.

P.S. As a side note, given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int arr[2] = {10, 20};
    X
    Y
    printf("%d,%d\n", arr[0],arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

where X was one of the following:

```
int *ptr = (int*)(void*)&arr;
int *ptr = (int*)&arr;
int *ptr = &arr[0];
```

and Y was one of the following:

```
ptr[0] = 15;
*ptr = 15;
```

When compiled on OpenBSD with gcc version 4.2.1 20070719 and providing the `-S` flag, the assembler output for all files was exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! However, you say that "Note though that casting from &arr to an int* might not give the correct results depending on compiler/implementation (to expand, see 6.3.2.3p5/6) but, in the case of this code, more than likely will since you're dealing with int types." -- in my opinion, 6.3.2.3p5/6 talk about converting pointers to integers and vice versa, whereas I'm converting a pointer of one type to pointer of another type.

Comment: @juhist, after some re-reading I agree, I've taken that note out but left the paragraphs for reference