# What Will The Declaration int (*ptr)[30]; Create?

Tags: c

What will `int (*ptr)[30];` create?
In general what happens if a variable name (in this case a pointer) is in parentheses ?

Comment: Very useful for questions of this nature: http://cdecl.org/. `int (*p)[10]` -> *declare p as pointer to array 10 of int*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this kind of question can always be answered by looking at the expression inside-out, with precedence considered.

in your case:

```
int (*ptr)[30];
```

can be viewed as

```
int (*ptr)[30];
-> ptr                 a variable called ptr
--> *ptr               which is a pointer
---> (*ptr)[30]        which points to an array with length of 30
----> int (*ptr)[30]   in which each element is of type int
```

if the parens are dropped, the story becomes:

```
int *ptr[30];
-> ptr                 a variable called ptr
--> ptr[30]            which is an array with length of 30
---> *ptr[30]          in which each element is a pointer
----> int *ptr[30]     and each individual points to an int
```

the same trick can always be applied to any expression about variable declaration.(note that function declaration is special. but it still can be analyzed in such way up to a point.)

Answer (score 4):

```
int (*ptr)[30];
```

Here ptr is a pointer to an array of type `int` with 30 elements.

So without the parantheses

```
int *ptr[30];
```

will create an array `ptr` which holds 30 integer pointers.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by the other answer, it's a pointer to an array of 30 integers.

How do you actually use these kinds of declarations:

```
int arr[30];
int (*ptr)[30] = &arr;
(*ptr)[0] = 5;
printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
```

So, it's a pointer to an array of 30 elements, not pointer to the first element of the array, although their memory addresses are the same (see [casting pointer to array into pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244504/casting-pointer-to-array-into-pointer)).

Note that `&arr` has a different type than `arr` even though when casted into `void *` they evaluate to the same addresses.

It's somewhat esoteric; you would use pointer to the first element of the array instead of pointer to the array itself most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `ptr` is a pointer to a 30-element array of `int`.

Postfix operators such as `[]` have higher precedence than unary operators such as `*`, so the expression `*a[i]` will be parsed as `*(a[i])` (`a` is an array of pointer).  To use a *pointer to an array*, you must explicitly group the unary `*` operator with the array name, such as `(*a)[i]` (`a` is a pointer to an array).

Handy table:

```
  *a[N]         -- a is an N-element array of pointer
(*a)[N]         -- a is a pointer to an N-element array
   *f()         -- f is a function returning a pointer
 (*f)()         -- f is a pointer to a function.
```