# Pointer to 2D Array(why does it work)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have the following function ( I want to print all elements from a given row)

```
void print_row(int j, int row_dimension, int *p)
{   
p = p + (j * row_dimension);

for(int i = 0; i< row_dimension; i++)
    cout<<*(p+i)<< " ";
}
```

Creating an array

```
int j[3][3]={{1,2,3},
             {4,5,6},
             {7,8,9} };
```

What I do not understand is why can I call the function in the following way :

```
print_row(i, 3, *j);
```

Why can I give as a parameter "*j" ? Shouldn't an address be passed? Why can I use the indirection operator?

Comment: Not really clear what the problem is. You are passing the address and inside the method you move the pointer

Comment: The code works, the problem is I do not understand why ( why can I call it like print_row(i, 3, *j) - with *j ) .

Comment: `auto t1 = j; // int (*t1)[3]` and `auto t2 = *j; // int *t2`

Comment: @flatmouse Why is `*j` a `int*`?  `*j` should be the same as `*(&j[0])` which should give you `j[0]`.

Comment: @NathanOliver `*j` does give you `j[0]`, which is an `int[3]` which then decays to an `int*`

Comment: @Kevin Oh duh, 2d array.  silly me.

Comment: @Kevin I have shamelessly used your comment in the answer. :)

Comment: @flatmouse no problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j` is in fact an array of arrays. As such, `*j` is an array of three integers, and when used as a rvalue, it decays to a pointer to its first element, said differently, it decays to &j[0][0].

Then in `printrow` you compute the starting address of the first element of  each subarray - that's the less nice part, I'll come back later to it. Then you correctly use the `*(p+i)` equivalent of `p[i]` to access each element of the subarray.

---

The remaining part of the answer is my interpretation of a strict reading of C standard

I said that computing the starting address of each subarray was the less nice part. It works because we all know that a 2D array of size NxM has the same representation in memory as a linear array of size N*M and we *alias* those representations. But if we respect **strictly** the standard, as an int pointer, `&p[i][j]` points to the first element of an array of three elements. As such, when you add the size of a row, you point past the end of the array which leads to undefined behaviour if you later dereference this address. Of course it works with all common compilers, but on an [old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30383876/3545273), @HansPassant gave me a reference on experimental compilers able to enforce controls on arrays sizes. Those compilers could detect the access past the end of the array and raise a run time error... but it would break a lot of existing code!

To be strictly *standard conformant*, you should use a pointer to arrays of 3 integers. It requires the use of Variable Length Arrays, which is an optional feature but is fully standard conformant for system supporting it. Alternatively, you can go down to the *byte* representation of the 2D array, get its initial address, and from there compute *as byte addresses* the starting point of each subarray. It is a lot of boiling plate address computations but it fully respect the @#!%$ strict aliasing rule...

TL/DR: this code works with all common compilers, and will probably work with a lot of future versions of them, but it is not correct in a strict interpretation of the standard.

Answer (score 3):

```
int j[3][3] = 
{{1,2,3},
{4,5,6},
{7,8,9}}; // 2d array

auto t1 = j; // int (*t1)[3]
auto t2 = *j; // int *t2
```

So what is happening is that `*j` produces `j[0]`, which is an `int[3]` which then decays to an `int*`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works because `*j` is a pointer which has the same value as `j` or `j[0]`. Such behavior caused by mechanics of how two-dimensional arrays are handled by the compiler.

When you declare 2D array:

```
int j[3][3]={{1,2,3},
             {4,5,6},
             {7,8,9}};
```

compiler actually puts all values sequentially in memory, so the following declaration will have the same footprint:

```
int j[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

So in your case pointers `j`, `*j` and `j[0]` just point to the same place in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Memory isn't multidimensional, so even if its a 2D array, it's data will be placed in a sequential manner, so if you get a pointer to that array -- that is implicitly a pointer to the first element of it -- and start reading the elements sequentially, you will iterate through all elements of this 2D array, reading element from the subsequent rows just after the last element of the previous one.