# Is comparing to a pointer one element past the end of an array well-defined?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, undefined-behavior

I learned by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29825352/5771029) that incrementing a NULL pointer or incrementing past the end of an array isn't well-defined behavior:

```
int* pointer = 0;
pointer++;

int a[3];
int* pointer2 = &a[0];
pointer2 += 4;
```

But what If the pointer pointing to a invalid place is only used for comparison and memory at his location is never accessed?

Example:

```
void exampleFunction(int arrayLen, char** strArray)
{
    for(char** str = strArray; str < strArray + arrayLen; str++) //or even str < &strArray[arrayLen]
    {
        //here *str is always a pointer to the first char of my string
    }
}
```

Here I compare my pointer to a pointer one element past the end of the array. Is this well-defined behavior?

Comment: When would the expression `*argv + argc` ever make sense? The length of `argv[0]` isn't related to `argc`. If you meant `argv + argc`, it's fine AIUI because pointers "one element past the end of the array" are well-defined and can be compared to other pointers in the same array. (Or `argv + argc + 1` because, as chux mentioned, `argv` ends with `NULL`.)

Comment: @chux Good to know ! I just have to use `<=` then. But the original question shouldn't take my mistake in consideration. Updated with better example

Comment: Your second code is OK as `str` is always a valid pointer.  It last value is not de-reference-able though.

Comment: The edited expression `*strArray + arrayLen` still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Incrementing *one step* past the end of the array is fine. Incrementing any further is not. `pointer2 += 4` is undefined behavior, but `pointer2 += 3` would not be, even though it would cause `pointer2` to point past the end of the array.

Comment: Note that "Is comparing to a pointer one element past the end of an array well-defined?" does not apply to the UB of `int* pointer = 0;
pointer++;`.

Comment: @chux The point was "does it matter if I create a pointer pointing to nothing as long as I don't use it to access" but the question was narrowed a bit to the example I provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comparing to a pointer *one step* past the end of an array is well defined. However, your `pointer` and `pointer2` examples are undefined, even if you do literally nothing with those pointers.

A pointer may point to one element past the end of the array.  That pointer may not be dereferenced (otherwise that would be [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) but it can be compared to another pointer within the array.

Section 6.5.6 of the [C standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) says the following regarding pointer addition (emphasis added):

> *8* If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, **or one past the last element of the array
> object**, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined**. If the result points one past the last element
> of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*`
> operator that is evaluated.

Section 6.5.8 says the following regarding pointer comparisons (emphasis added):

> *5* When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. **If two
> pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point
> one past the last element of the same array object, they compare
> equal.** If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate
> object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater
> than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and
> pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare
> greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower
> subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object
> compare equal. **If the expression P points to an element of an array
> object and the expression Q points to the last element of the same
> array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P. In
> all other cases, the behavior is undefined.**

In the case of `pointer1`, it starts out pointing to `NULL`.  Incrementing this pointer invokes undefined behavior because it don't point to a valid object.

For `pointer2`, it is increased by 4, putting it *two* elements past the end of the array, not one, so this is again undefined behavior.  Had it been increased by 3, the behavior would be well defined.

Comment: Is not the "one passed" rule applies to non-array objects too?  `int x; int *p = &x+1;`

Comment: @chux You may be right.  Section 6.5.8 part 4 says *"For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an
array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
type of the object as its element type.*"  Section 6.5.6 part 7 has the same wording.

Comment: The quoted 6.5.8 applies to `<`, `<=`, `>=`, and `>`.  The `==` and `!=` operators never yield Undefined Behavior when given pointers to objects, pointers "just past" objects, or null pointers.  A comparison between a pointer "to" one object and a pointer "just past" another may report equality, but that does not imply the pointers may be used interchangeably.

Comment: Does this also apply to the element one before the array? I'm asking because I'm needing to iterate in reverse and the nicest idiom would be a pointer one step before the first element.

Comment: @LeviMorrison it does not

Comment: @LeviMorrison: IMHO, the best way to understand the allowance for "just-past" pointers is to recognize that each object has two associated addresses: one for the start and one for the end.  An array of three elements will have four associated address: start of first, between first and second, between second and third, and end of third.

Comment: @LeviMorrison Start with one-past-the-end, pre-decrement instead of post-decrementing, and use `>= start` instead of `< end` as the loop predicate.