# Iterator on dynamic array in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, iterator, adt

How can I make an iterator over a dynamic array (in a struct)?

Comment: This is not C#, please check your tags

Comment: cont_begin and cont_end are inconsistent with each other.  one is returning the value of an element in a->array, the other is returning the address.

Comment: while it is UB to access outside the bounds of your array, it is legal to point 1 element past the bound.  so `return a->array + a->size` is legal.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45335768/8767209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamic array, as represented by type `struct _Lista`, *does not* contain "elements of any type".  At least not directly.  It contains only and exactly elements of type `void *`.  Pretty much everything you've written will work if you change type `iterator` accordingly, to a *double* pointer:

```
typedef void **iterator;
```

Do note, however, that this iterator implementation has a severe flaw: it does not carry any information about the bounds of the list.  That may be OK if you ensure that there is a sentinel value after the last valid element (and maybe before the first, too), but otherwise you'll need a more complex data structure than just one pointer.