# Is a range-based loop over a default constructed std::span undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, nullptr, std-span

I am wondering whether a range based loop over a default constructed `std::span` is defined behavior since I am conditionally assigning to a default constructed `std::span` before looping. For example can I do the following?

```cpp
#include <span>

int main()
{
    std::span<char> s;
    for (auto c : s) {
        // do something
    }

    // should be equivalent to
    for (char* p = nullptr; p < (char*)(nullptr) + 0; ++p) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29825553) says the following about additive expressions involving pointers:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So strictly speaking, the operation of adding 0 to `(char*)(nullptr)` is undefined because the operand `(char*)(nullptr)` does *not* point to an element in the same array object.

I am wondering if this case is still defined behavior?

I think it is well-defined because the following code does not compile:

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr char* a{nullptr};
    constexpr char* b{a+1};
    return 0;
}
```

But it *does* compile if we replace `a+1` by `a+0`. So there must be indeed a special rule which allows adding 0 to a `nullptr`.

Comment: I didnt dig into details, but if you default construct a `std::vector` its `data()` may be `nullptr` as well. What matters is the iterators returned by `begin` and `end` and that they compare equal

Comment: `// should be equivalent to` not quite. Read here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Yes there is special requirement in [expr.add] about adding 0 to null pointer resulting with null pointer.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.1

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Indeed, so if I replace `<` by `!=` it would be a correct reformulation (except for plugging values into the variables)?

Comment: The rule about adding zero to a null pointer, resulting in a null pointer has existed in all C++ standards since C++98.   In C++98, it is in Section 5.7 "Additive Operators", para 8,  "If the value `0` is added to or subtracted from a pointer value, the result compares equal to the original pointer value. If two pointers point to the same object or function or both point one past the end of the same array or both are null, and the two pointers are subtracted, the result compares equal to the value `0` converted to the type `ptrdiff_t`."

Comment: @phinz  You're missing 46's point.   You're incorrect in equating a range-based `for` to something involving a null pointer.   The actual equivalence (which has evolved a little between C++ standards) is described in the link that 46 provided, and will be in terms of `s.begin()` and `s.end()` (or of `std::begin(s)` and `std::end(s)` which are equivalent for a `span`, and compare equal for an empty span `s`).

Comment: better don't make assumptions about implementation details. I see nothing that would require an implementation to do this addition of `nullptr +0`. What an implementation has to do is: make `begin` and `end` return iterators that can be compared to be equal, also for a default constructed span.

Comment: @Peter I understand now. But how do you know they compare equal for an empty span? Is this enforced in some specifications? Without having read this guarantee, I checked [gcc's](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/b59775b642bb2b1ecd2e6d52c988b9c432117bc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/span#L315) and [clang's](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/d74619abb53bc9c5680f83bb1dead9c65135ecc6/libcxx/include/span#L526-L531) implementations (where span::end() add `0` to `nullptr`) but I acknowledge it is just one possible implementation. Where do you read that `begin()==end()` for a default span?

Comment: @phinz `begin()==end()` is the definition of empty. Also it's explicitly spelled out: https://wg21.link/views.span#span.iterators-3

Comment: @Artyer @Peter Thank you this answers my question! Obviously people that closed this question for being a duplicate of adding 0 to `nullptr` also missed 46's point.

Comment: @phinz -  While looking at low level (gory) implementation details of a library (e.g. gcc's or clang's library) has its uses, it is not a good way to understand how to *use* the library.  The standard (not a particular implementation) is the authoritative definition, and where the standard is hard to read (as it often is) there are reference sites (like en.cppreference.com) and introductory texts on C++ that are somewhat easier to understand.  It is the standard that specifies that all standard containers - including `std::span`, if empty, have equal begin and end iterators.

Comment: well the thing is that your question has a false premise. As such, there are different ways to approach it. One can either address `nullptr + 0` or the "what happens to an empty span in a range based loop?", they just arent as much related as you expected