# C memcpy 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memcpy

I'm trying to copy one 2D array to another using `memcpy`. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int print(int arr[][3], int n) {
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < n; ++c)
            printf("%d ", arr[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[3][3] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };
    int arr_copy[3][3];

    print(arr, 3);
    memcpy(arr_copy, arr, 3);
    print(arr_copy, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
-1426063359 32726 -1902787872 
22012 0 0 
-1902788416 22012 48074240
```

I also tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    memcpy(arr_copy[i], arr[i], 3);
```

Why above codes don't work and how I should correct?

Comment: The third argument to `memcpy()` is the number of bytes to copy. Why are you passing only 3?

Comment: `memcpy(arr_copy, arr, sizeof(arr_copy))`

Comment: `memcpy(arr_copy, arr, sizeof arr);` should do it - or `for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) memcpy(arr_copy[i], arr[i], sizeof arr[i]);` for the second version

Comment: @TedLyngmo does second version have any benefit over the first one?

Comment: @ElginCahangirov My C knowledge is a bit dated, but I suspect that the first version technically has UB (_undefined behavior_) while the second version does not.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Can't see any UB in the first (simpler) version. Each array will occupy contiguous memory.

Comment: @AdrianMole I know they occupy contiguous memory and I can't swear that it's UB in C. It is in C++ though.

Comment: @Ted Nope. Still don't understand. *Why* is it UB (in C++)?

Comment: @AdrianMole In C++ you aren't allowed to access an array out of bounds. Any attempt to do so has undefined behavior - even in this case where the first inner array is known to be followed by the 2 other arrays.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think there's any out-of-bounds here. Just like `memcpy` works for an array of `int`s, it works for an array of `int [3]`s, and both should be contiguous (but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 The out of bounds access happens when you copy the first byte from `arr[0][3]`. I've never seen it actually fail, but, in C++, it has UB.

Comment: Hmm - interesting. Maybe worth a C++/Language-Lawyer question.

Comment: @AdrianMole [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139579/2d-array-indexing-undefined-behavior) seems to touch on the subject.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think the `arr[0][3]` thing applies. By that logic, I think copying the second `int` of an `int` array through `memcpy` would be UB as well. `int [3]` is simply the type of `arr`'s elements, and the bounds of `arr` as a whole in bytes should be `sizeof (int [3]) * 3`. I'm probably missing something though :/

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 The second `int` in an `int` array (of at least 2 `int`s) is within the array bounds and copying it has defined behavior. Accessing `int[0][4]` in a `int[3][3]` is out of bounds of the first inner array though.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes, but also arrays declared this way are contiguous and one object. I see no way to get UB from `memcpy(arr_copy, arr, sizeof arr)` as long as `arr_copy` is sufficient size.

Comment: @Ted Maybe. But the `memcpy` function/call doesn't do any array indexing - it's just given two `void*` pointers and copies memory from one to the other.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I guess you're right. I still don't entirely agree since we're talking about `arr` as a whole, no subarrays or anything, and since we're `memcpy`ing only `sizeof arr` bytes it should all be in the bounds of `arr`, but I guess we are just going in circles now.

Comment: @AdrianMole I can't say for sure if that matters in C. In C++ it doesn't. You get a pointer to the first `int[3]` and any access out of its range has UB. I haven't found any exception to that in the C++ standard.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `struct obj { int arr[3][3]; } a_2d_arr, a_copy;` and `memcpy(&a_copy, &a_2d_arr, sizeof a_2d_arr);` should be a safe workaround.

Comment: @Ted - I raised the issue in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69329884/10871073). Hope you don't mind that I quoted you. (Also, what ***is*** UB is the `int print` function not returning anything!)

Comment: @AdrianMole No, I don't mind at all. I read a description of _why_ it's UB a long time ago but I haven't found it since then so I hope that whomever wrote that description shows up to answer :-)

Comment: @AdrianMole That certainly became a popular question :-) I'm glad to have gotten my misconceptions straightened out.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah - I'm surprised how much debate it triggered. There's some good stuff in the answers ... I'll need to have a thorough read (or two) before deciding which one to award the "Green Tick" to ...

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, there are a lot of angles and standards quoting going on - and I noticed a few more answers have come in. Exciting stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The size is in bytes, so you copy only 3 bytes - not even one integer.

```
memcpy(arr_copy, arr, 3);
```

You can see how big your array is by printing its size in bytes:

```
printf("sizeof(arr) = %zu\n", sizeof(arr));
```

So the correct memcpy code should be:

```
memcpy(arr_copy, arr, sizeof(arr));
```

Same error here:

```
memcpy(arr_copy[i], arr[i], 3);
```

It has to be:

```
memcpy(arr_copy[i], arr[i], sizeof(arr[i]));
```