# Is it legal to have an std::array of C-style array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Can I use something like `std::array<int[2][2], 2>` as a substitute for `int[2][2][2]`, just like `std::array<int, 2>` can be used instead of `int[2]`?

What I really need is maybe a statically-sized multidimensional array that

1. Have "proper" value semantics, and
2. Is stored contiguously in memory.

It seems that, unlike C-style arrays, `std::array` of `std::array` is not guaranteed to have fully compactified memory, as `std::array` may contain padding.

What are possible issues I might have if I use something like `std::array<int[2][2], 2>`? Perhaps this is a too vague question, but it's hard to figure out why exactly I'm not comfortable and somewhat doubtful using it for my purpose.

Comment: The trick is to abstract away the dimensions.  Use a `std::array<int, 8>` and wrap in a class, overload the `()` operator to provide element access as if it is 3d instead of flat.

Comment: i dont know what to tell you. if you are not comfortable with it then dont use it. create your own array class or use cstyle array.

Comment: Why do you need to store these elements contiguously?

Comment: This question is hard to answer, because I can't come up with any potential "issue" of this use, though this array looks not very natural.

Comment: @liliscent That's exactly what I feel right now.

Comment: @xskxzr Because I need to use a single pointer to iterate over the array. With padding, things will become complicated.

Comment: Another thing you could do is assert the size is correct.  Something like `static_assert(sizeof(std::array<std::array<std::array<int, x>, y>, z>) == sizeof(int) * x * y * z, "Array has padding");`  If that doesn't fire you know you are safe

Comment: The iteration possibly [results in undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6016700/5376789). You'd better think of other ways.

Comment: @xskxzr Interesting. I've never know that. Thank you. Now it seems that I should do what NathanOliver suggested, though making a fully generic & compatible & not-bloated multidimensional array class seems to be very non-trivial...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it results in undefined behavior.

The `value_type` of a container [must be *Erasable* from the container type](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#tab:containers.container.requirements), where Erasable is defined in [[container.requirements.general] paragraph 15](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#15):

> Given an allocator type `A` and given a container type `X` having a `value_­type` identical to `T` and an `allocator_­type` identical to `allocator_­traits<A>​::​rebind_­alloc<T>` and given an lvalue `m` of type `A`, a pointer `p` of type `T*`, an expression `v` of type (possibly `const`) `T`, and an rvalue `rv` of type `T`, the following terms are defined. If `X` is not allocator-aware, the terms below are defined as if A were `allocator<T>` — no allocator object needs to be created and user specializations of `allocator<T>` are not instantiated:
>
> - ...
> - `T` is *Erasable from `X`* means that the following expression is well-formed:
>   `allocator_traits<A>::destroy(m, p)`

Because `std::array` is not allocator-aware, we need to check if `allocator_traits<allocator<int[2][2]>>::destroy(m, p)` is welll formed.

Since [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) has no member function `destroy` (deprecated in C++17), [`std::allocator_traits::destroy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/destroy) would call the (pseudo) destrutor of `int[2][2]` directly. This [is ill-formed](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.pseudo#2) because `int[2][2]` is not a [scalar type](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#9).

Comment: This seems to me to be a defect.  You can't erase members of a `std::array` as it is an aggregate.  It doesn't use an allocator at all.

Comment: It is explicitly mentioned in the standard that ````std::array```` should satisfy all the requirements of Container (except some things irrelevant here), so technically this answer seems to be absolutely correct. Thank you!