# reachability with std::launder

Tags: c++, c++17, stdlaunder

I'm trying to understand the following snippet from [CPP reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder). Can someone explain in a little more detail why `x2[1]` is unreachable from `source` ? Can't we reach it via `&x2[0][0] + 10` for example?

```cpp
int x2[2][10];
auto p2 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(&x2[0][0])); 
// Undefined behavior: x2[1] would be reachable through the resulting pointer to x2[0]
// but is not reachable from the source
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reachability condition basically asks whether it is possible to access a given byte of memory via pointer arithmetic and `reinterpret_cast` from a given pointer. The technical definition, which is effectively the same, is given on the linked cppreference page:

> (bytes are reachable through a pointer that points to an object Y if those bytes are within the storage of an object Z that is pointer-interconvertible with Y, or within the immediately enclosing array of which Z is an element)

`x2` is an array of 2 arrays of `10` arrays of `int`. Let's suppose we call the two arrays `a` and `b`.

`&x2[0][0]` is an `int*` pointing to the first element of `a`.

`&x2[0][0] + 10` is an `int*` pointer one-past the last element `a`. The address of this pointer value is also the address at which `b` begins. However one cannot obtain a pointer to `b` or one of its elements via `reinterpret_cast` since `&x2[0][0] + 10` doesn't point to any object that is pointer-interconvertible with `b` or one of its elements.

In terms of the technical definition, the only object pointer-interconvertible with the first element of `a` is the object itself. Therefore the reachable bytes from a pointer to the first element of `a` are only the bytes of `a`, which is the array *immediately* enclosing this object.

Therefore the reachable bytes through `&x2[0][0]` are only those of the array `a`, not including `b`. E.g. `*(&x2[0][0] + 10) = 123;` has undefined behavior.

However if `std::launder` were to return a pointer to `a` (of type `int(*)[10]`), then `(p2+1)[i]` would be a way to access all elements of `b`. Or in terms of the technical definition, the array *immediately* enclosing the object `p2` points to would be `x2`, so that all bytes of `x2` are reachable.

This means after the `std::launder` bytes that weren't reachable before would become reachable. Therefore the call has undefined behavior.

Comment: It's not reachable through the source since ```&x2[0][0] + 10``` is an ```int *``` vs. ```int (*)[10]``` ? IOW, the former is not pointer-convertible to the latter.

Comment: @user3882729 Pointer-interconvertibility is a property between objects. The type of pointers doesn't determine the type of the object they are pointing to. So the problem is not the type, but rather that `&x2[0][0] + 10` doesn't point to any object at all, so trivially it cannot be pointing to any object which is pointer-interconvertible with any other object of any type.

Comment: W.r.t. pointing to a valid object this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015080/c-c-is-this-undefined-behavior-2d-arrays#comment6953450_6015221) mentions doing any arithmetic beyond pointer increment is UB. Perhaps access of ```&x2[0][0] + k``` is only defined for ```k < 10``` and for all other values does not point to a valid object consequently making them unreachable

Comment: @user3882729 `k>10` is UB, but `k=10` is allowed. However, the resulting pointer is not a pointer pointing to an object. It is a one-past-the-object pointer and may not be dereferenced.

Comment: The standard itself didn't mention this example, and I think `x2[1]` is reachable after the `reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>` instead of after `std::launder`. So there's no UB. The precondition "All bytes of storage that would be reachable through the result are reachable through p" is about implicit conversions like `std::launder<Base>(&derived)`

Comment: @TuffContender `std::launder<Base>(&derived)` is equivalent to `Base* x = &derived; std::launder(x)` and this `std::launder` call is redundant because `x` must already be pointing to the base class subobject after the conversion. I am not sure where you consider reachability to come in. A `reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>` does not change the pointer value, so the resulting pointer still points to the array element instead of the array, because array elements and arrays are not pointer-interconvertible. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#compound-note-4

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks a lot, now I see the precise meaning of pointer values.